# Laravel add additional array of dates while model retrieving

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have relationship between User and Attendance, where in Attendance table I have field `start` and `end` which are `date` fields. I'm able to retrieve the data through relationship. I'm getting User Absences for current month and afterwards I want to add "additional" field/variable/attribute with array of this dates(parsed to Carbon) to User model. Is it possible?

I was trying to use `booted()` method with `static::retrieved` function, where I call another.

When I need to check those absences in view to display a Calendar I iterate too many times (previously I've created a method inside Users model to retrieve and parse those data).

I need to achieve something like this:

```
if(in_array($someDates, $user->additional_array)) [...]
```

Previously I've got:

```
if(in_array($someDates, $user->methodToReturnAdditionalArray())) [...]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Laravel Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) and define the new method for getting the data you want

Example:

```
public function getAdditionalArrayAttribute()
{
    // return the list of array items you want;
}
```

And then you can use it like here:

```
$model->additional_array;
```

Comment: It's not that easy to implement this in my approach, because in view I iterate through each `$dayInMonth` then in each `$user` so it doubles the queries unnecessary. I need to have an information if it's possible to achieve it only while retrieving the model from database in one only case - f.e. while entering specific route/view, but thanks for reply.